# how to send the multiple form (screen) data to the same request in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-props

i want to send the multiple form details to the single api in react native

one of my friend suggest me to try to make a form object inside the parent component and then pass the form object to the children form and bind it. And then on Submit just post the data which is in the object. but i'm new to this and i'm not getting how to do that if anybody share me the sample code. i mean example how to do that'll be helpful

Answer (score 1):

That should be easy:

```
var formData = new FormData();
fromData.append('key1','value1');
fromData.append('key2','value2');
```